# substr function for substract the column value basis of another column in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to use substr function in oracle to substract the column value 
 based on another column vale in same table.
 For example:suppose table abc having some column value like `a=01-CEDAPR` while  `B=AB_52MM_01-CEDAPR`

Now i want to populate the column c on the basis of value AB_52MM. can any one suggest me 
what is right way to achieve this .

Comment: Provide sample input and output

Comment: input:a=01-CEDAPR B:AB_52MM_O1-CEDAPR, O/p:ab_52_mm,But problem here i want to rejected the string from last _ on wards.you can say (-_) it can be any position like some time in -8 or -9

Comment: How about output column c

Comment: forget about column c..just give me any sample query from retrieve this value from column a and b

Comment: @psaraj if possible plz help me in that issue..

Comment: Please add info to the question, not as comments. It still isn't clear; do you want to truncate the `b` value from the last underscore, or just remove the end part that matches underscore and the value in `a`? Or something else?

Comment: Hmm, you've got `01-CEDAPR` in column A, but it looks like you're expecting to remove `O1-CEDAPR` from column B. 0 != O ... was that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of solutions that may or may not help you, based on the sketchy information you have provided. If they don't, then you will need to edit your question to provide more a more detailed explanation of what you're after!

```
with sd as (select '01-CEDAPR' a, 'AB_52MM_01-CEDAPR' b from dual) -- assumed O1 in column b was a typo
select a,
       b,
       regexp_replace(b, '_'||a),
       substr(b, 1, instr(b, '_', -1) -1) 
from   sd;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be relatively straightforward. All you want to do is replace the value of `a`, if found in `b`, with nothing. Right?

```
WITH abc AS (
  SELECT '01-CEDAPR' AS a, 'AB_52MM_01-CEDAPR' AS b
    FROM dual
)
SELECT a, b, REPLACE(b, a)
  FROM abc
```

[See SQL Fiddle Demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40196)

If you need to replace the `_` preceding the value of `a`, then you might want to use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` (in case the `_` may or may not exist):

```
WITH abc AS (
  SELECT '01-CEDAPR' AS a, 'AB_52MM_01-CEDAPR' AS b
    FROM dual
)
SELECT a, b, REGEXP_REPLACE(b, '_?' || a || '$')
  FROM abc
```

The `$` sign ensures that the value of `a` is anchored to the end; the `?` makes `_` optional.

[SQL Fiddle Demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40198)